# Tomcat, memory leak char[] and ThreadWithAttributes

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, tomcat6

I have tomcat (Apache Tomcat/6.0.18) that appears to have a memory leak.

### Preliminary analysis

At one point on several servers heap utilization exceeded 90%. Then I made a heap dump and its analysis which pointed to two possible leaks:

> 4 550 instances of "char[]", loaded by "" occupy 321 358 144 (42,39%) bytes.
>
> Biggest instances:
>
> char[5102000] @ 0xd18668c8 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u00... - 10 204 016 (1,35%) bytes.

---

> 392 instances of "org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadWithAttributes", loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader @ 0xbb003c30" occupy 151 940 704 (20,04%) bytes.

Where char[5102000] is repeated many times and is filled with null.

### Analysis

#### org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadWithAttributes

Dominator tree analysis indicates that the main culprit is CA Wily Introscope.

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════╗
║   Class Name                                                                          ║        Objects         ║  Shallow Heap   ║  Retained Heap  ║  Percentage ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadWithAttributes                                   ║ 392                    ║        53 312   ║    151 940 704  ║ 20,04%      ║
║ #-java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry                                          ║  254 047               ║     8 129 504   ║    146 384 296  ║ 19,31%      ║
║ ##- com.wily.util.adt.CanonicalObjectPoolWithKey                                      ║ 391                    ║        12 512   ║     72 506 184  ║ 9,56%       ║
║ ##- java.util.HashMap                                                                 ║  199 734               ║     7 989 360   ║     40 377 784  ║ 5,33%       ║
║ ###- com.wily.util.adt.WeakWeakIdentityHashMap                                        ║ 391                    ║         9 384   ║     11 503 344  ║ 1,52%       ║
║ #java.util.HashMap$Entry                                                              ║  207 683 #  4 984 392  ║     16 396 456  ║ 2,16%           ║             ║
║ ####- com.wily.introscope.agent.trace.BlamePointTracer$DataAccumulatorGroup           ║   49 807               ║     1 593 824   ║      1 593 824  ║ 0,21%       ║
║ ####- com.wily.introscope.agent.trace.servlet.ServletObjectFactory$MethodKey          ║    2 563               ║        61 512   ║         62 840  ║ 0,01%       ║
║ #####- com.wily.introscope.stat.gatherer.IntegerAverageGatherer                       ║ 92                     ║         5 152   ║         10 304  ║ 0,00%       ║
║ #####- com.wily.introscope.stat.gatherer.IntervalCounterGatherer                      ║ 109                    ║         4 360   ║          4 360  ║ 0,00%       ║
║ #####- com.wily.introscope.stat.gatherer.IntegerFluctuatingCounterGatherer            ║ 55                     ║         3 080   ║          3 080  ║ 0,00%       ║
║ #####- com.wily.introscope.stat.gatherer.IntegerAggregatingFluctuatingCounterGatherer ║ 54                     ║         3 024   ║          3 024  ║ 0,00%       ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

#### char[]

Dominator tree analysis shows nothing - the only point of accumulation is char[]. Analysis "Merge Shortest Paths to GC Roots" points directly to the org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadWithAttributes.

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║                                        Class Name                                        ║  Ref. Objects  ║  Shallow Heap  ║  Ref. Shallow Heap  ║  Retained Heap ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadWithAttributes @ 0xd0b12cb8  TP-Processor203 Thread ║              1 ║ 136            ║         10 204 016  ║        240 216 ║
║ - <Java Local> char[5102000] @ 0xd18668c8  \u0000\u0000...                               ║              1 ║    10 204 016  ║         10 204 016  ║     10 204 016 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

### Question

What is responsible for creating many objects char [] filled with null? How to remedy that does not take up much space in the hea?.

Comment: Can you try running with the latest Tomcat 6.0.x release (or better yet the latest 7.0.x release)? Tomcat has added some memory leak detection / protection code and the logging from that might provide some pointers.

Comment: @MarkThomas Perhaps it would have been a possibility, but I would have to know the style - this is a known bug in the Tomcat with a number xxx.

Comment: The issue you describe looks like an application memory leak. It doesn't match any Tomcat bug I can recall. The logging in the newer versions is likely to help you track down the source.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable JspWriterImpl Pool, add this paramaters on JRE launch command :

```
-Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.USE_POOL=false -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true
```

This will release JspWriterImpl buffers after use

Answer (score -1):

With the little information you presented, it is hard to tell where the issue could be. In addition TomCat is very well known to be neither stable nor bug-free, so the leak could be in TomCat itself as well.

If you cannot find the problem manually, you can use a static code analysis tool like [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) (free, open source), to scan the code for you.

Comment: Presented as much information as I was able to extract from the heap dump. If you put them too little, please write anything else you need.